# Why the Link tag in react routers is not showing me the desired page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, router, react-props

I was trying to fetch data through a news API and there were different categories of news with the help of react-router I want to show news of different categories, the link tag is working as it is changing the local host URL but the page is not showing the particular news category. Can anyone help me out?

This is the `App.js`,

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Navbar from './COMPONENTS/Navbar';
import News from './COMPONENTS/News';
import {
BrowserRouter,
Routes,
Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
export default class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <>
      <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar/>
    <News category="general"/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/business" element={<News key="business" category="business"/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/sports" element={<News key="sports" category="sports"/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/health" element={<News key="health" category="health"/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/politics" element={<News key="politics" category="politics"/>}></Route>
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the  `VerticalNav.jsx` file, here are all the links,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
export default class VerticalNav extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <>
            <nav className="navbar2">
                    <ul className="ul_list">
                        <li className="vertical_comp">
                            <Link className="avertical_comp" to="/business">Business</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="vertical_comp">
                            <Link className="avertical_comp" to="/sports">Sports</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="vertical_comp">
                            <Link className="avertical_comp" to="/health">Health</Link>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

And this is the file where I am using props,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import NewsItem from './NewsItem'
 import Spinner from './Spinner';
import VerticalNav from './Verticalnav';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
export default class News extends Component {
static defaultProps = {
   category : 'general',
 }

 static propTypes = {
  category : PropTypes.string,
 }
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  article: [],
  page: 1,
  loading: false,
}
 }

    async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
     loading: true
    })
let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines? country=in&category=${this.props.category}&
     apiKey=6aeca0faebbd45c1a1ec3c463f703ebb`;
   let data = await fetch(url);
    let parseData = await data.json();
   this.setState({
      article: parseData.articles,
     loading: false
    });
   }

  handleNext = async () => {
   let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines? 
  country=in&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=6aeca0faebb
    d45c1a1ec3c463f703ebb&page=${this.sta 
  te.page + 1}`;
     this.setState({ loading: true });
  let data = await fetch(url);
  let parseData = await data.json();
   this.setState({
   page: this.state.page + 1,
  article: parseData.articles,
  loading: false
    })
 console.log(this.state.page);
    }
  handlePrevious = async () => {
  let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines? 
 country=in&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=6aeca0faebbd45c1
  a1ec3c463f703ebb&page=${this.sta 
 te.page - 1}`;
 let data = await fetch(url);
   let parseData = await data.json();
this.setState({
  page: this.state.page - 1,
  article: parseData.articles,
  loading: false
    })
   }

  render() {
  return (
  <>
  <div className="vertical">
  <VerticalNav/>
  <div class="card1">
          <h1 className='mainheading' >THE PAHADI PRESS HEADLINES OF THE DAY</h1>
    <div class="row row1">
        {this.state.loading && <Spinner />}
          {this.state.article.map((e) => {
            return <div class="col-md-4 colu" key={e.url} >
              <NewsItem title={e.title} decription={e.description} imageUrl={e.urlToImage} 
               newsUrl={e.url}
                newsauthor={e.author} source={e.source.name} />
            </div>
          })
         }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please check if you need <News category="general"/> this line below <Navbar/>, I think it is loading news component with general category because this component is getting loaded on each route

Comment: Yes Just observed that the page is loading and showing up I clicked at some link which were dummy, but the page is showing after the general news not in place of that, can you tell me what to do to bring new page in place if the general news.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to move the `general` `News` component inside the `Routes`:

```
return (
  <>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
      <Route
          path='/'
          element={<News key='general' category='general' />}
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path='/business'
          element={<News key='business' category='business' />}
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path='/sports'
          element={<News key='sports' category='sports' />}
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path='/health'
          element={<News key='health' category='health' />}
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path='/politics'
          element={<News key='politics' category='politics' />}
        ></Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </>
);
```

Comment: oh yes this is working,I have to do this everytime?

Comment: Your component should not be called where routes are created, because this main component is rendered on every route